# "Click to translate" for .pdf

Tags: windows, pdf, translation, interactive

Is there a way to be able just click a word and get its translation while reading .pdf files?
Google Dictionary is very useful plugin for Chrome but works only for web pages. Does something similar exist to use with .pdf?

I'm using Windows. I've found plugins for Chrome built-in reader. All them do nothing in pdf.
I can use any other pdf reader if there is one with such translation plugin, but can't find anything like that.

Comment: What operating system or PDF reader? What answers did you find and why are they no longer relevant?

Comment: Windows. I can use any available reader. Now using Adobe Reader (or Chrome built-in one). I've found plugins for Chrome built-in reader. All them do nothing in pdf. I expect some non-Chrome solution, like some plugin for Adobe Reader.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that (important) information.

Answer (score 11):

In my option for Windows the best option is QTranslate. Just select any word or text and double press CTRL.

QTranslate will automatically popup window with translation and additional info (depending on service you selected)

You can set input/output languages, translation service (google, yandex, etc...).

It has many other features and options.

And it's free!

And it's just 1 MB!

https://quest-app.appspot.com/home

Comment: That was very usefull also for me , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The one extension I know work with chrome'spdf viewer is called [reference.com dictionary lookup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referencecom-dictionary-l/eeepadhockifhkeglihhapjdhkcpcfal) it will dd the extension and just select the text and then right click to translate it. From the store...

`Simply adds an icon to the address bar and to the right click menu whenever you select text on a page. Clicking the icon or the menu item will open a new tab at reference.dictionary.com to show you the definition of the word(s) you have selected.`

You can also try [instant translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-translate/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke) and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox + Quick Translator works fine for me. However Quick Translator is not available for current version (40) of Firefox. You can either find another addon or download an old Firefox browser just for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Download Foxit reader. it is pdf program with translate option. Great program. much better than adobe reader. and it is FREE.

The other option is Babylon, it is perfect and contains all the dictionaries and languages. but it is very expensive. it works with mousewheel click.